# c# Bot Framework client and Server timezone difference

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I create a chatbot using MS bot framework where initially i will send a welcome message like "Good morning UserName" but my bot is hosted in azure and i user DateTime.Now to find the time of the day and provide the greeting message accordingly. But if some user from different timezone uses "Good morning " and "Good afternoon" messages are not appropriate.

How can i overcome this?

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour < 12)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Good Morning");
}
else if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 12 and DateTime.Now.Hour < 17)
{
    await context.PostAsync("Good Afternoon");
}
else
{
    await context.PostAsync("Good Evening");
}
```

Comment: You may need to use javascript to get the local time on the client and pass that back to your server.

Comment: can you provide an example of how you're handling the message and date/time logic?

Comment: @Matt webchat is sending me only the message to my bot API and it's not send the client time

Comment: @AussieJoe If(DateTime.Now.Hour <12) {await context.PostAsync("Good Morning")};
else if(DateTime.Now.Hour > 12 and DateTime.Now.Hour < 17) {await context.PostAsync("Good Afternoon")};
else {await context.PostAsync("Good Evening")};

Comment: According to https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md you have to create a BackChannel. That allows you to communicate client side information to your server and use it in your Web Chat Bot

Answer (score 1):

If you embed webchat in your website, as Matt mentioned in comment, you can use the [backchannel mechanism](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/README.md#the-backchannel) to pass `TimezoneOffset` from JavaScript client to your bot application to achieve your requirement.

***In JavaScript client:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wc-chatview-panel {
            width: 350px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="bot" />
</body>
</html>
<script>
    var botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({ secret: "{directline_secret}" }); 

    var d = new Date();
    var tzoffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();

    BotChat.App({
        botConnection: botConnection,
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'fehanbotdg' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("bot"));


    botConnection.postActivity({
        type: 'event',
        from: { id: 'userid'},
        name: 'ClientTimezoneOffsetEvent',
        value: tzoffset.toString()
    }).subscribe(function (id) { console.log('ClientTimezoneOffset: "' + tzoffset + '" sent'); });
</script>
```

***In bot application MessagesController:***

```
private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
{
    if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
    {
        // Implement user deletion here
        // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
    }
//......
//code logic for other messages types
    //......
    else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Event && message.Name == "ClientTimezoneOffsetEvent") {

        int timezoneOffset = Convert.ToInt32(message.Value);

        var client = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl), new MicrosoftAppCredentials());

        timezoneOffset = Convert.ToInt32(message.Value);

        DateTime newDate = DateTime.UtcNow - new TimeSpan(timezoneOffset / 60, timezoneOffset % 60, 0);

        var greeting = "";

        if (newDate.Hour < 12)
        {
            greeting = "Good Morning";
        }
        else if (newDate.Hour > 12 & newDate.Hour <= 17)
        {
            greeting = "Good Afternoon";
        }
        else if (newDate.Hour > 17 & newDate.Hour <= 24)
        {
            greeting = "Good Evening";
        }

        var reply = message.CreateReply();

        reply.Text = $"{greeting}! UTC time: {DateTime.UtcNow}; Client time: {newDate}";

        client.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }

    return null;
}
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: Hi @LM1015, if the reply could help you solve the problem, you can mark it as accepted answer, which would also help other community members quickly find the solution and solve similar issues.