# How to convert datetime coming as a string input from user as text in webchat bot into utc using c# by getting the culture info dynamically?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

I display a prompt in my Web chat bot developed using sdk v4 and c# to enter datetime when user enters the date time it comes to the code as a string or text message now I don't know which time zone time the user has entered, now what I wanted to to know how to dynamically know the culture info dynamically so that I can convert it into utc appropriately.

Currently, I am able to convert A date time to utc but it is not converting appropriately for example I get a date time input in the following format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm I take it and convert it into date time using datetime parse or datetime.Parseexact then to utc I get output as what the user has given even after conversion. I tried to give the culture info as IST assuming it as IST and then tried to convert but the issue is the same.

I have tried conversion using datetime offset and also culture info as invariant but also it is same issue.

For example: the input is 2019-06-09 13:45 then tried to take this value and applied all the above methods to convert to utc but I get back the same output I.e 2019-06-09 13:45 which has no difference b/w input and output.

Is there anything special I have do to do for latest framework of. Net?

If yes what things I have to do, please explain in an step by step detailed manner as I am new to coding and bot.

I am using the following:
Visual studio 2019
Botframework : v4
Channel : webchat channel
Framework:.net 7.2
Langugae:c#

I tried datetime. Parse, datetime. Parse exact, tried to provide some time info for example purposes that did it work tried to provide culture info as invariant that also did not work tried to provide some culture info like IST related that also did not work.

Expected result: conversion should be successful and there should be some difference observed
Actual result: conversion is successful but no difference in input and output.

Comment: You need to detect the user's timezone, here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396878/c-sharp-bot-framework-client-and-server-timezone-difference

Comment: your frontend should send the datetime in ISO format. ISO format send date in T Z Format e.g "2019-06-10T05:57:58.659Z"

Comment: @Shantanu: If i understand correctly, do you mean the user enters the date in format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm then when it is coming it to you convert it into ISO format as given by you above and the go for conversion, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes get the date from user convert it to ISO format and then send to server ,this way server has the UTC date

Comment: @LennartStoop: I have gone through the link provided by you it seems the code is in V3 format and the HTML script also in old format, is it possible for you to provide it in update V4 SDK format and the HTML script using the es5 bundle. I tried it from my side it did not work, so thinking if i did something wrong so requesting you to provide HTML script in es5 bundle and code in V4 so that i can compare it my side of code with it and correct wherever required? Please let me know if anything is needed form my end on this request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Culture info pertains more to the format of a date (MM-DD-YY vs DD-MM-YY) than to things like time zones. As the comments have explained, you will need to explicitly send time zone information to the bot yourself. [This sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) explains how to send a welcome message through backchannel in Web Chat v4.

[The linked question from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396878/c-sharp-bot-framework-client-and-server-timezone-difference) explains both how to retrieve the user's time zone information and how to interpret it in your bot. To apply that to Web Chat v4, just include the time zone information in the value of the event:

```js
var d = new Date();
var tzoffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
// When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
dispatch({
  type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
  payload: {
    name: 'webchat/join',
    value: tzoffset.toString()
  }
});
```

Since the activity schema hasn't changed, the v3 bot code can still be applied to a v4 bot. But instead of using a connector client, you can send messages with the turn context:

```cs
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

If you want to use the Web Chat ES5 bundle, just replace `webchat.js` with `webchat-es5.js`.

Comment: :Thanks for your help i think i understood it now, i was just confused whether it was not working because of V3 vs V4 template problem but now based on your explanation i understood a bit more about BOT and other things. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @ Lennart Stoop: Thanks to you also for the initial guidance that really helped.